# Sharing a keychain item across multiple applications on Mac OS X

Tags: javascript, macos, keychain

I am working on a project which has a web application and a desktop application. User goes through the web application to download the desktop application.

The current design requires the user to enter the credentials in the web application to download the desktop application. Once the desktop application is downloaded and launched, it again asks for user credentials. I am trying to figure out if there is anyway I can save something (cookie or keychain entry) on the user machine when the web application is run and then access that information in the desktop application to avoid asking for credetials again.

So far I have only been developing desktop applications, so I am not sure about the possible options for this design.

Is keychain entry the right approach for this kindof problem ? 
Is it even possible to create a keychain item on Mac OS X from javascript ?

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated !

Thanks,
Abhinay

Comment: what kind of javascript? from the browser? then no.

Comment: If the user is already required to enter their credentials to use the application, couldn't you just provide the download without requiring credentials?